# Как определяется "главная копия переменной" в многопоточной программе?

Tags: java, многопоточность

[Читаю](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/) (стр 378) (*прошу прощения за большую выдержку из источника*):

> Модификатор доступа `volatile` сообщает компилятору, что модифицируемая им переменная может быть неожиданно изменена в других частях программы. Одна из таких ситуаций возникает в многопоточных программах, где иногда у двух или более потоков исполнения имеется совместный доступ к одной и той же переменной. Из соображений эффективности, в каждом потоке может храниться своя закрытая копия этой переменной. **Настоящая ( или главная) копия переменной** обновляется в разные моменты , например, при входе в синхронизированный метод. Такой подход вполне работоспособен, но не всегда оказывается достаточно эффективным. Иногда требуется , чтобы главная копия переменной постоянно от­ражала ее текущее состояние. И для этого достаточно объявить переменную как `volatile` , сообщив тем самым компилятору всегда использовать главную копию этой переменной ( или хотя бы поддерживать любые закрытые ее копии обновляемыми по главной копии, и наоборот). Кроме того, доступ к главной копии переменной должен осуществляться в том же порядке, что и к любой закрытой копии.

**Вопрос:**

В каждом потоке может храниться своя копия переменной. Как определяется "**главная копия переменной**" в многопоточной программе? В каком потоке она "главная"? Модификатор доступа `volatile` определяет? Но ведь все потоки видят эту переменную одинаково.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как определяется "**главная копия переменной**" в многопоточной программе?

Под главной копией переменной здесь подразумевается та переменная, значение которой актуально на данный момент.

> В каком потоке она "главная"?

Если переменная объявлена как `volatile`, то в любом потоке она будет главная, в противном случае можно ожидать любое другое поведение (где-то она будет главная, а где-то – нет).

> Но ведь все потоки видят эту переменную одинаково.

Если переменная объявлена как `volatile`, то все потоки будут видеть эту переменную одинаково, в противном случае потоки могут закешировать эту переменную и, в таком случае, другие потоки уже не увидят актуальное значение этой переменной.

**Ключевое слово `volatile` гарантирует видимость переменной**. То есть переменная, объявленная с таким модификатором, в любой момент времени в любом потоке будет иметь актуальное значение.

Приведу небольшой пример:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        Thread checkThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                foo.checkValue();
            }
        });
        checkThread.setName("Check Thread");
        checkThread.start();

        Thread incThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                foo.incValue();
            }
        });
        incThread.setName("Inc Thread");
        incThread.start();
    }

    private static class Foo {
        private volatile int mValue;

        public Foo() {
            mValue = 1;
        }

        public void checkValue() {
            int localValue = mValue;
            while (localValue < 5) {
                if (localValue != mValue) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": value = " + mValue);
                    localValue = mValue;
                }
            }
        }

        public void incValue() {
            for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": value = " + mValue);
                mValue++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Поток `checkThread` копирует значение `mValue` в локальную переменную `localValue` и крутится в цикле до тех пор, пока `localValue < 5`. При этом, в цикле проверяется условие `localValue != mValue`, если оно истинно (это означает изменение переменной `mValue`), то локальной переменной `localValue` присваивается текущее значение `mValue`.

Поток `incThread` инкрементирует переменную `mValue` с паузами в 500 миллисекунд, пока ее значение не достигнет 5.

Если переменная `mValue` объявлена как `volatile`, то Вы **всегда** получите **строго такой** вывод на консоль:

```
Inc Thread: value = 1
Check Thread: value = 2
Inc Thread: value = 2
Check Thread: value = 3
Inc Thread: value = 3
Check Thread: value = 4
Inc Thread: value = 4
Check Thread: value = 5
```

Если переменная `mValue` НЕ объявлена как `volatile`, то Вы не можете гарантировать, что вывод на консоль будет **всегда** такой же, как и в предыдущем случае. Он может быть и такой же, а может и другой, например такой:

```
Inc Thread: value = 1
Inc Thread: value = 2
Inc Thread: value = 3
Inc Thread: value = 4
```

или такой:

```
Inc Thread: value = 1
Check Thread: value = 2
Inc Thread: value = 2
Inc Thread: value = 3
Inc Thread: value = 4
```

В случае, когда переменная объявлена как `volatile`, после ее инкрементирования в потоке `Inc Thread`, поток `Check Thread` сразу же видит это изменение.

В случае, когда переменная НЕ объявлена как `volatile`, в первом выводе на консоль видно, что поток `Check Thread` вообще не увидел изменение этой переменной, а во втором случае – увидел только первое инкрементирование.